# Unity light turning off when switched to baked?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, light

I've been trying to set up some baked lights for my Unity project, and whenever I switch a light's mode to baked, it turns off completely. No error messages, just a light that's off, and as soon as I set it back to real time and generate the lighting, it's back.

My lightmap settings:

[image]

My light settings:

[image]

My shader settings:
[image]

The result with a realtime light:

[image]

Aaaaaand the result with a baked light, which, yes, I have narrowed down to it being dark even though it doesn't quite look that way. 
[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check Generate Lightmap UVs in Model import settings